# HTML Canvas not displaying my rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


<script>
 window.onload = function(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("map"),
        c = canvas.getContext("2d");

    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect = (20, 30, 50, 250);

    c.fillSyle = "white";
    c.fillRect = (50,50,25,25);
};
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="map" width="800" height="400">
        <img src="images/sad dinosaur.jpg" />
        You will need an updated browser to view this page!
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I am just tinkering a bit with canvas trying to get a feel for how it works. However, the tutorial video I am watching shows the coding for the c.fillRect and the c.fillStyle in the exact same format that i have shown in my code yet my screen only displays the black rectangle from the first set of instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `fillRect` is `c.fillRect(...)`, as opposed to `c.fillRect = (...)`. Compare your last two calls with your first call.

Also, your last `fillStyle` is mistyped as `fillSyle`.

```js
window.onload = function () {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("map"),
        c = canvas.getContext("2d");

    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect(20, 30, 50, 250);

    c.fillStyle = "white";
    c.fillRect(50, 50, 25, 25);
};
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3fLyknt2/)